# Problem in loading dynamic shared c++ library from Python

Tags: python, c++, shared-libraries, loadlibrary

I've built a project *SharedProj* that is linked to .so. It links 4 more projects, that are built to static libraries: *libA.a, libB.a, libC.a, libD.a*. These projects are set as references in *SharedProj.so* and linked with -l flag.

When I try to load *SharedProj.so* from Python with **cdll.LoadLibrary**, it fails with exception: "cannot find *libA.so* - no such file".
Yes, it's really true: there's no *libA.so* and not supposed to be. There's *libA.a*, that is linked statically.

What is the problem here? How do I build *SharedProj.so* properly, so Python will load it correctly?

I've tried linking *SharedProj.so* with -shared or -shared-libgcc flags.
Tried to build the static libraries with -static or -static-libgcc flags.
Tried to add or remove -fPIC flag.

Comment: Instead of using the `-l` flag to reference the static libraries, when you build your main `.so`, you probably need to reference the `.a` files explicitly. If `-l` finds a `.so` it will use it, instead of a `.a`. Without seeing your exact build script or makefile, nothing more can be suggested.

Comment: `gcc -shared -o yourModule.so -fPIC yourModule.c` Which system you are compiling is very important. The library you created must also have a working right. If found in the same directory as the Python application, many access problems do not occur. Also, if the buffer memory definitions are missing, your application returns an error or irrelevant data. **In C, the data type is byte, you cannot return any other data type**

Comment: On Sunday I'll be back at work, will check out your suggestions and copy here the exact build script. Thanks

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik, @dsgdfg, OK, so I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 with gcc v5.4. Building my projects with Eclipse Neon CDT, so gcc invocation is made from an auto-generated makefile. The linker invocation line is as following:  `g++ -m64 -shared -o "EvaluationModule.so" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $LIBS)`  When before that $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) are defined as the other static libs, listed with absolute path to the .a files.  I've removed the -l flags.  Now the results are that the Python shouts that method  in the static libs are undefined symbols. It doesn't see their implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm on a closed itranet, so I can't actually send the script here.  The building line for each of the static libs is: `g++ -std=c++1y -I"my path to project file" -O0 -g3 -Wall -m64 -c -static -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"file.d" -MT"file.o" -o "file.o" "file.cpp"`  and the GCC Archiver: `ar -r "libFile.a" ./File.o`

Comment: Unfortunately, integrated build environment are generally incapable of correctly implementing non-standard builds, such as the mixed static/shared library build you are attempting to do. All they support is simple use cases. Build an executable. Build a bunch of shared libraries. That's it. Your only option is to switch to low-level build tools, such as GNU automake, where you have complete control over the resulting Makefile, and can tailor it accordingly.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik, if you're right, I don't have much choice. Can you understand what is the problem in current build line I've written above? I mean, if I accept your suggestion, I still don't know why Python either now recognizing the symbols of static libs' methods, or trying to find the .so files instead of .a..

Comment: Something in the Makefile did not link the static libraries into the shared library. Can't really say much more about it. Maybe there's something in your build environment that can specify that a particular library should be built only as a static library, instead of static+shared. Then, by specifying that a shared libraries links with this particular library your build environment will create the correct commands in the Makefile, for that. Additionally it can't be a regular link, because that'll pull in only syms referenced in the shared lib, you want everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem in Eclipse IDE.
Apparently, the problem was that my static *libs libA.a, libB.a, libC.a* have used another libs, like *math* lib, and I haven't specified the linker where it must search for them.
In the final link directive I pass with -L flag the folders of my static libs AND the */lib* folder. With -l flag I specify the names of the static libs: *libA, libB, libC*. Also the following flags are included: *-shared -shared-gcclib -m64*
Also, a directive to the linker to pull all the symbols into the .so must be included: -Wl,--whole-archive all_the_static_libs.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive. So, finally, the linkage line looks like this:

```
g++ -L"%workspace/libA/Debug" -L"%workspace/libB/Debug" -L"%workspace/libC/Debug" -L/lib -Wl,--whole-archive -llibA -llibB -llibC -Wl,--no-whole-archive -m64 -shared-libgcc -shared -o "SharedProj.so" ./SharedProj.o
```